# CF7 Add a read only attribute to an input field

Tags: jquery

I have a function that validates an input field if a checkbox is checked:

```
jQuery("input[type='checkbox'][value='Internet Search']").click(function(){
    if (jQuery("input[type='checkbox'][value='Internet Search']").prop('checked'))
    {
        validatetext("input[name='internetSearch']", 4, 12, "input[type='checkbox'][value='Internet Search']");
    } else {
    errors[12] = true;
        checkInput("input[name='internetSearch']",errors[12]);
    }
});
```

What I'd like to do is add a read only attribute to the if/else statement. How would this be written?

Comment: Can you provide more details on what you mean by "read only attribute"? Perhaps provide an example?

Comment: Umm, did I miss something? How is this related to wordpress?

Comment: @VitorArgos sure, if your creating an input field in a form you can add attribute="read only". That will make it so the field is visible, but you can't add text to it. So in the function above I'm say, if the check box "internet search" is checked make the text input field Internet search a required field. What I want to do is make the text field read only until the check box is clicked.

Comment: @YobdDigital I'm using contact form 7 to create the form, and am creating an additional JS file for my conditional checkbox functions.

Comment: Even if this is a contact 7 question it's still off topic because that is not directly related to WordPress, but it's a javascript question so technically it belongs on stackoverflow. Just trying to save you running the risk of getting a question closed in the future

Comment: @VitorArgos OK, but how would I combine the code with what I've already written? Basically have two things happen once the checkbox is selected, make the field Internet search required and remove read only access.

Answer (score 0):

It`s not completely clear to me how your fields are organized but adding the following piece of code to your if statements should help making the desired input "readonly":

```
jQuery('input[name="internetSearch"]').prop('readonly', true);
```